# How do I make font of a button to bold on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, fonts

Currently I'm running on windows 10 when I go to services the services button are sort of different from my friend pc font button

My pc font button:

[image: My pc font button]

My friend's pc button:

[image: My friend's pc button]

How do I make my font button to look alike just like the one my friend had?. I have asked on microsoft and done several googling but none of them seems to answer my question.

Comment: This looks like a scaling issue, your friends image is slightly fuzzier which is why the text looks slightly bolded. It's actually not. Your image is sharp, because you don't have any scaling. Your machine is showing the button as it's intended to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **Ease of Access** (just type that after opening the start menu).

You can change text scaling by changing the 'Make everything bigger' function:
[image]

You probably have it set to 100% (which is unscaled and crisp), your friend probably uses the default 150% (which makes it easier to read but is fuzzier).